# Creating TWO way trusts between two AWS managed Active Directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, active-directory

I am trying to create a two way trust between Two AWS Active Directories.
I can establish the One way Incoming trust but while creating a two way or a One-way Outgoing trusts it says "Verify failed".

I have done all DNS configuration and can create one way incoming trusts.

Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an older post now, but did ensure that you've setup the 2-way trust on both sides? The first one you initiate (Domain1) will say that verification failed.

Then you go to 2nd domain and set up the same way, using the same password you used for Domain1 trust, it should succeed. Then you go to back to Domain1 and choose option to verify trust again.

Also make sure your inbound / outbound ports are allowed to communicate.

Comment: thanks mbspark . i did the same way and trust was created .